# Best practice with AutoMaping ViewModel (DTO) to Model (Entity)

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I've happily been using AutoMapper in a few projects and made use of `.ReverseMap()` when going from ViewModel to Model. I'd typically do the following:

```
// run at startup
// I'd customize the mapping if needed
Mapper.CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>().ReverseMap();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SomeModel viewModel)
{
    var data = Mapper.Map<Model>(viewModel);
    _repo.Insert(data);
    _uow.Save();
    return View();
}
```

Then I find this article: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/

I'm at a loose.

Is the article simply outdated or is there a better way?

Comment: What exactly bugged you in the article?

Comment: Well the article as a whole. But this quote sums it up: "I can’t for the life of me understand why I’d want to dump a DTO straight back in to a model object."

Comment: As always, it depends on the complexity of your domain. If you feel that your DTO *can* be mapped back to an Entity without much hassle then two way mapping is good for you. For complex domain models it sometimes simply can't work.

Comment: I see, thanks. Am I correct in assume that manual mapping is used in these complex scenarios?

Comment: I think the core problem is the usage of 'One DTO to rule them all'. In complex scenarios you usually can't pass back the same 'Read DTO' (Entity -> DTO) but rather you create a special DTO specific to the requested operation, so you eventually end up with a 'Command' (that's only my take, there are obviously other approaches).

Answer (score 2):

***A disclaimer first***: There are all kinds of different domains and architectures and this answer may not apply to your design goals or architecture at all. You're of course free to use AutoMapper however you want. Also, I did not write the article, so I'm using my own experience with certain types of projects to come up with an answer.

---

### The importance of the domain layer

First of all, the article in question assumes you are using some version of [domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_driven_design). At the very least, I'd say it appeals to the idea of a domain that's a very important part of the project and should be "protected." The bit that best sums this idea up is:

> ...Because then our mapping layer would influence our domain model.

The author did not want artifacts outside of the domain layer updating the domain.

Why? Because:

- The domain model is the heart of the project.
- Modification to the domain layer should be a serious operation--the most important parts handled by the domain layer itself.

The article mentions a few problems with allowing the mapping piece of the solution to do domain model updates, including:

> Force mutable, public collection , like `public EntitySet<Category> Categories { get; }` <- NO.

You might wonder why having a mutable, public collection is a bad thing--from a domain model perspective you probably don't want some external service blasting in (possibly invalid) categories whenever it wants.

A more sensible API for adding Categories in this case would be:

- have `AddCategory` and `RemoveCategory` methods that the entity itself does some validation on before adding.
- Expose an `IEnumerable<Category> { get; }` that could never be modified by outside consumers.

A project I worked on recently had a quite complex domain. Domain entities frequently were only updated after prospective update operations were run through several validation services (living in the domain).

We would have introduced a huge design problem had we allowed mapping *back* to domain entities.

Allowing AutoMapper (or another mapping project) to map directly to our domain entities would be subverting the logic in the domain entities (or more likely domain services that performed validation) and creating a kind of "back door" into the domain layer.

### Alternative

Hopefully the commentary above provided a little help. Unfortunately the alternative when you're *not* doing automatic mapping is to use plain ol' `=`. At the very least, though, if you're in a DDD environment you'll be forced to think a little more about what should happen before a domain entity is created or updated.

### However

... The `.ReverseMap` method exists. I think this article still rings true for a certain type of project. The built-in ability to automatically create a two-way mapping means that the library is able to handle applications beyond the target application.

As stated in the disclaimer, two-way mappings might make total sense for your application.

Comment: ReverseMap is used primarily for DTO <-> DTO mappings. Like ViewModel -> Command etc.